# Relative frequency of $0$ in decimal repersentaion of $\sqrt{2}$ expansion

Tags: number-theory

Demonstrate that the relative frequency of $0$ in the $\sqrt{2}$ is approximately $\frac{1}{10}$. The first $0$ is at the $13$ digit after the coma.

Comment: There doesn't seem to be any question here. Is this a homework problem that you're expecting people to do for you without doing any work of your own?

Comment: How is the frequency of a digit in a number in decimal format defined?

Comment: Let me rephrase : i have to demonstrate that the frequency of 0 in the decimals of the square root of 2 is 1/10

Comment: A rather simple way to phrase this question is to prove that $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{f(n)}{n} = \frac{1}{10}$ where $f(n)$ counts the number of $0$'s in $\sqrt{2}$'s decimal representation in the first $n$ digits. However, this problem may be open I think.

Comment: Once you have solved this problem, you may claim your Fields Medal.

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to determine the frequency of digits in the decimal expansions of irrational numbers other than to compute the number and count up the digits.

You may find an expansion of $\sqrt 2$ in a book of tables or on the internet suitable for your purposes, or you could compute it yourself using Newton-Raphson, for example. But your conclusion can only be that the digit $0$ turns up/does not turn up one tenth of the time in *up to so many decimal places* of $\sqrt 2$.

Comment: I assume you mean, "There is no _known_ way...".

Comment: @TonyK, Yes, it has not been proven to be an impossible task. See for example this page from [Mathworld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/NormalNumber.html).